# mySql Query need to add values even if user is not mapped to the rule

Tags: mysql

I Am Passing user id 30 so im direcrly gonna get it from the map table

**Permission Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `permissions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `right_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `dateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `permissions` (`id`, `right_name`, `dateTime`) VALUES
(1, 'Upload', '2017-09-04 15:07:25'),
(2, 'Export PDF', '2017-10-10 12:12:52'),
(3, 'Add Adapter', '2017-10-04 13:01:30'),
(4, 'Generate Template', '2017-10-09 17:15:36');
```

**User_permission Map**

```
CREATE TABLE `user_permission_map` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `u_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dept_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `user_permission_map` (`id`, `u_id`, `p_id`, `dept_id`) VALUES
(1, 30, 1, 1),
(6, 30, 3, 1),
(11, 30, 2, 2),
(12, 30, 1, 2);
```

What Im getting

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|  right_name           dept_id    p_id  u_id  |
+----------------------------------------------+
| Upload                     1    1       30   |
| Add Adapter                1    3       30   |
| Export PDF                 2    2       30   |
| Upload                     2    1       30   |
| Generate Template        NULL   NULL    null |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Using this query

```
SELECT `permissions`.`right_name`, `user_permission_map`.`dept_id`, `user_permission_map`.`p_id`
FROM `permissions`
LEFT JOIN `user_permission_map` ON `user_permission_map`.`p_id` = `permissions`.`id` 
AND user_permission_map.u_id=30
```

**What i want to achieve is**

```
  +---------------------------+----------------------+--------------+
|         right_name        |            dept_id   |  p_id  u_id  |
+---------------------------+----------------------+--------------+
|         Upload            |                    1 | 1       30   |
|         Upload            |                    2 | 1       30   |
|         Add adapter       |                    1 | 3       30   |
|         Add adapter       |                    2 | 3       null |
|         Export PDF        |                    1 | 2       null |
|         Export PDF        |                    2 | 2       30   |
|         Generate Template |                    1 | 4       null |
|         Generate Template |                    2 | 4       null |
+---------------------------+----------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a calendar table approach to ensure that every department/permission combination appears in the result set:

```
SELECT
    t2.right_name,
    t1.dept_id,
    t1.id AS p_id,
    t3.u_id
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.dept_id, t2.id
    FROM user_permission_map t1
    INNER JOIN permissions t2
) t1
INNER JOIN permissions t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN user_permission_map t3
    ON t1.id = t3.p_id         AND
       t3.dept_id = t1.dept_id AND
       t3.u_id = 30;
```

Functionally speaking, the only major difference between my query and your original attempt is the subquery which I labelled `t1`.  If you run this query in isolation, you will see that it calculates every distinct combination of departments and permissions.  In fact, the two columns it returns looks almost like your expected output, minus the user id column.  Then we join this table to your two original tables to fill in the missing values we want.

Note that I do an inner join to `permissions` because there is no chance of losing any information.

In case you are wondering, this type of computed table is called a calendar table becauee this approach is often used when we want to e.g. display every day in a calendar month when our underlying data is missing information for some of the days.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: hey its seems to almost work  just that in the Add Adapter for department 2 is showing 30 when it should be null   same for export pdf

Comment: ohh cheers man...thank you  so much ...  im gonna now sit  and study this